# php to node.js ajax sending does not give response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, node.js

I was trying to post some data from my php page to my node.js server.and I want to get the response from it.

This is the ajax code which I was sending from my php page which is currently executing on the apache server

```
function encryptCode()
{
  var value = document.getElementById("code").value;
  $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:3000/insertUser",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(value),
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function(data) 
                {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });   
}
```

and I just want to receive it in my node.js page by this code

```
var BaseController = require("./Base"),
    View = require("../views/Base"),
    model = new (require("../models/ContentModel"));

module.exports = BaseController.extend({ 
    name: "insertUser",
    content: null,
    run: function(req, res, next) {
        model.setDB(req.db);
        var self = this;


    console.log(data);

        /*this.getContent(function() {
        //  var v = new View(res, 'place');
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify(self.content));


        });*/
       // console.log("go to hell");


    },
});
```

This is a controller of my express.js,which I have redirected from my app.js page with this code

```
app.all('/insertUser', attachDB, function(req, res, next) {
            insertUser.run( req, res, next);
        });
```

will somebody please help me out in the console.log I am getting {} .....

Comment: what is the value of variable  "value" in your php code Line ::>>> var value = document.getElementById("code").value;

Comment: ok do you know about the debugging in node js

Comment: @Hiren the "code" is the value which I will get from my HTML page

Comment: @Ahmer not upto the mark brother

Comment: assuming in textbox you have enter some text and if it is not JSON value, then it wont parsed in node.js. So you want get result in your controller

Answer (score 0):

First test is it problem with the frontend.

```
function encryptCode()
{
  var value = document.getElementById("code").value;
  console.log(value);
  $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:3000/insertUser",
                type: "POST",
                data: {"user":value},
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function(data) 
                {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });   
}
```

You should set json body parser in your express app

```
var app = express();
bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

where did you declare `data` variable. In node.js the data sent through ajax request is available at `req.body`

```
var BaseController = require("./Base"),
    View = require("../views/Base"),
    model = new (require("../models/ContentModel"));

module.exports = BaseController.extend({ 
    name: "insertUser",
    content: null,
    run: function(req, res, next) {
        model.setDB(req.db);
        var self = this;  
        console.log(req.body);
        // console.log(req.body.user);
    },
});
```

Comment: Sir I have already done it..but this is returning me {}
fat gaya yar

Comment: yes sir and I have fixed it by contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", //This is what made the difference. line

Comment: you are sending the data as string, that might be the problem. Once check the updated answer